# Why isn't it possible to use "await" in f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string

Why isn't it possible to use "await" in f-strings? Is there any way to coerce f-strings into evaluating the format expressions in the context of a coroutine function?

```
$ python3 
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar  4 2017, 12:32:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> async def a(): return 1
... 
>>> async def b(): return 'The return value of await a() is {}.'.format(await a())
... 
>>> async def c(): return f'The return value of await a() is {await a()}'
... 
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (await a())
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Python `3.6`, this *is not possible*. It will be possible in `3.7` according to the messages on [Issue 28942 -- await expressions in `f-strings`](https://bugs.python.org/issue28942) on the Python bug tracker.

As for the reason, the author of the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) that introduced `async`/`await` expressions, Yury Selivanov, had this to say:

> I suspect the reason is that `async`/`await` aren't proper keywords in
>   3.5/3.6, and the hacks we have in tokenizer to recognize them aren't working in f-strings.
>
> I'll assign this issue to myself to make sure it's resolved in 3.7
>   once we make `async`/`await` keywords.

and indeed, the tokenizer does seem to [treat these specially](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.h#L69).

You were right to be puzzled by this as formatted strings are documented as supporting [all valid Python expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (with the appropriate limitations those expressions entail i.e `await` in an `async def` function).

I don't believe there's any way to circumvent this at the moment. You'll need to stick with the `.format` route until the issue is resolved.